# Two matrix summation functions returning different values

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm messing with two matrix summation functions, one with threading and one without. I'm splitting up the matrix, which is a 3-dimensional matrix, 1000 x 1000 x 1000, into two threads so that a one-half of the matrix is summed while the other half is summed and then I add those two together. That is the threaded function, which takes a dimension of the matrix as an argument, and only sums the values within those dimensions.

The other function sums the matrix without splitting it up, it goes through all one billion values.

Here is the threaded function:

```
long double myFunction(double*** a3DArray, int dimLower, int dimUpper){
    long double aValue = 0.0;
    for (int i = dimLower; i < dimUpper; i++) {
        for (int j = dimLower; j < dimUpper; j++) {
            for(int k = dimLower; k < dimUpper; k++) {
                aValue += a3DArray[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    return aValue;
}
```

I believe I've written it correctly, but that's why I'm here, to see if someone sees anything glaring that I can't.

Here is the non-threaded one:

```
long double sumArray(double*** a3DArray, int m, int n, int l) {
       long double sum = 0.0;
       int i, j, k;
       for (i = 0; i<m; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j<n; j++) {
               for(k = 0; k<l; k++) {
                   sum += a3DArray[i][j][k];
               }
           }
       }
       return sum;
    }
```

And here is the `main`

```
int main(){
    int dim = 1000;
    double ***my3DArray = new double**[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i<dim; i++) {
        my3DArray[i] = new double*[dim];
        for(int j=0; j<dim; j++) {
            my3DArray[i][j] = new double[dim];
            for (int k=0; k<dim; k++) {
                my3DArray[i][j][k] = 2.3;
            }
        }
    }
    auto thread1 = std::async(myFunction, my3DArray, 0, 500);
    long double myOutput = thread1.get();
    auto thread2 = std::async(myFunction, my3DArray, 500, 1000);
    myOutput += thread2.get();
    long double ThreeDArraySum = sumArray(my3DArray, 1000, 1000, 1000);
}
```

In `main`, I build the matrix, each value being 2.3, and I call both functions, first two threads that split the matrix in half and then just the standard summing.

I get different values though, and I'm unsure if it's because of the summation functions or the creation of the threads. I have the right #includes and everything, I get 9e+08 for the threaded calculation, and 2.3e+09 for the non threaded. Any advice you guys could give would be really appreciated, trying to learn the benefits of threading.

Comment: Try a thought-experiment with dim=2.  Is your threaded version actually summing the entire 3D array?

Comment: I believe so, I tried switching all the for loops in the threaded function to <=, to no avail.

Comment: Off topic: If you are going for speed, consider a 1D array with manual indexing. Right now you literally have over a million arrays scattered around your RAM and that's going to play hell on your cache.

Comment: I made some progress, by making _k_ iterate to 1000, but it's still not quite equal.

Comment: Your array has `1000^3 == 1000*10^6` elements. Each call to `myFunction` goes over `500^3 == 125*10^6` elements. You make two such calls. `125+125 != 1000`.

Comment: Another way to look at it: which call, do you believe, visits `my3DArray[0][900][900]`?

Comment: Neither, you're right. However I can't think of how to assign the threads to cover [0][900][900]. I feel it's simple but my brain is fried.

Comment: Imagine a 1000x1000x1000 cube. Take an imaginary knife and cut it in half. What are the dimensions of the two resulting pieces?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubik+cube+2x2&tbm=isch) will help.

Comment: That makes sense, I actually just figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case each of `myFunction` call used `500*500*500` elements. In total you used `2*500*500*500` = `250*10^6`, at the same time your 3d array have `1000*1000*1000 = 1000*10^6` elements. Your `myFunction` must looks like this:

```
long double myFunction(double*** a3DArray, int dimLower, int dimUpper, int matrixSize) {
    long double aValue = 0.0;
    for (int i = dimLower; i < dimUpper; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < matrixSize; k++) {
                aValue += a3DArray[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    return aValue;
}
```